# Unroll nesting in recursive map in clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm having trouble unrolling the nested structure of the results of this function. I *think* it's performing the traversal correctly but the results are deeply nested.

The function attempts to traverse the list and find all of the possible paths through the list where the numerical distance between adjacent elements is either 1, 2, or 3. For example, to go from the first element 1, to the next element 4 only a step of 3 will work. But, for the next step we can either take 1 from 4 to 5, we can take two from 4 to 6 (skipping 5), or three from 4 to 7 (skipping 5 and 6).

My question is two fold: 1) what can I do to prevent the deep nesting? and 2) is there a different way to structure the code to prevent the deep nesting in the first place?

```
(def l0 (1 4 5 6 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22))

(defn next-path-with-step [chain step]
  (let [looking-at (first chain)
        next-path (drop-while (fn [a]
                                (not (= (- a looking-at) step)))
                              chain)]
    (if (empty? next-path)
      nil
      next-path)))

(defn find-chains [chains prefix]
  (if (empty? chains)
    prefix
    (map (fn [chain]
           (let [head (first chain)
                 next-paths (filter #(not (nil? %))
                                    (map (partial next-path-with-step chain) [1 2 3]))]
             (find-chains next-paths (conj prefix head))))
         chains)))
```

To run it:

```
(find-chains [l0] [])
```

I get the following results:

```
(((((((((((([1 4 5 6 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22]))))) (((([1 4 5 6 7 10 12 15 16 19 22]))))))) ((((((([1 4 5 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22]))))) (((([1 4 5 7 10 12 15 16 19 22]))))))) (((((((([1 4 6 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22]))))) (((([1 4 6 7 10 12 15 16 19 22]))))))) ((((((([1 4 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22]))))) (((([1 4 7 10 12 15 16 19 22])))))))))
```

What I'm trying to get are the inner sequences as a list. Something like:

```
([1 4 5 6 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22] 
 [1 4 5 6 7 10 12 15 16 19 22] 
 [1 4 5 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22] 
 [1 4 5 7 10 12 15 16 19 22] 
 [1 4 6 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22] 
 [1 4 6 7 10 12 15 16 19 22]
 [1 4 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22] 
 [1 4 7 10 12 15 16 19 22])
```

Comment: leetwinski has given you a good solution to the problem as stated, but I must say I would be surprised if this algorithm were efficient enough to solve the Advent of Code problem you're working on in time - it's faster than brute-forcing the 2^100 possible solutions, but still has to look at each actual solution once. The solution for my input was a 14-digit number, far too many to produce them all one at a time.

Comment: @amalloy you are correct! It is not efficient enough to solve the problem (it exhausts the heap). I started down this path with the short example given to see if I could get the same results that they did since I knew I would have trouble getting the recursion and list construction. I've been struggling with nested lists wanted to know where my gap was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here are the minor changes, that will solve that for you:

```
(defn find-chains [chains prefix]
  (if (empty? chains)
    [prefix] ;; return chain wrapped in a vector to avoid flattening
    ;; use mapcat instead of map to flatten internal find-chains calls
    (mapcat (fn [chain] 
              (let [head (first chain)
                    next-paths (filter #(not (nil? %))
                                       (map (partial next-path-with-step chain) [1 2 3]))]
                (find-chains next-paths (conj prefix head))))
            chains)))

user> (find-chains [l0] [])

;;=> ([1 4 5 6 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22]
;;    [1 4 5 6 7 10 12 15 16 19 22]
;;    [1 4 5 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22]
;;    [1 4 5 7 10 12 15 16 19 22]
;;    [1 4 6 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22]
;;    [1 4 6 7 10 12 15 16 19 22]
;;    [1 4 7 10 11 12 15 16 19 22]
;;    [1 4 7 10 12 15 16 19 22])
```

Comment: ugh! Such a simple change. I'm a little embarrassed I couldn't see it!